RegAsm vs Visual Studio's "register for COM interop"
I've always thought that executing the RegAsm tool with the /codebase /tlb /u options is also what visual studio does when checking the "Register for COM Interop" option in a project's properties, but while the /codebase RegAsm option requires an assembly to be signed visual studio does not. Here an answer confirming my current understanding. Is someone able to clarify how things really stand?

/codebase options does not require the assembly to be signed. Note all this is gone with .NET Core (where you use regsvr32 on a generated myfile.comhost dll, back on the old days). Reg-free is indeed still a good option. But what's your question exactly?

You are right, you get what is really only a warning "RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can cause your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be installed on the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it.".
My question is if indeed VS calls on regasm for registering .NET framework assemblies. I've put VS output to verbose and I don't see a trace saying that regasm has been called,

BTW I've seen examples of .NET assemblies exposing a COM interfaces being registered with regsvr32 and I was confused somehow by this, your answer has cleared out why that is, I was not aware that starting with .NET core we are back to regsrv32 as for unmanaged DLLs

Visual Studio doesn't use regasm, it uses an MsBuild task called "RegisterAssembly" https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/src/Tasks/RegisterAssembly.cs which uses this RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.registrationservices.registerassembly Regasm also uses RegistrationServices but how it enters it is not strictly the same but very similar. None of this is relevant to .NET Core but you're not the only one confused :-)

I noticed that VS OOB also registers the type library for a .NET component although this might not really be needed
